# Minecraft Forge - gradlew - Invalid patcher dependency

Tags: minecraft-forge

I am trying to create my first mod for Minecraft and I have problem when I try the command "gradlew genIntelij Runs". I've been trying changing system variables but I'm not sure what I'm doing. Could You please help me?

```
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

> Configure project :
Java: 1.8.0_301 JVM: 25.301-b09(Oracle Corporation) Arch: amd64
New Dep: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.3-34.1.42_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Tutorial'.
> Invalid patcher dependency: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.3-34.1.42:userdev

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

Answer (score 1):

`Invalid patcher dependency: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.3-34.1.42:userdev`, most likely, your dependencies did not install correctly.
Clear your gradle caches and run the command `gradlew eclipse` to resolve all dependencies again and your problem should be solved.

I also recommend upgrading to 1.16.5 or 1.17.1 because you can get better help and patches for them.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem

`> Configure project :
Java: 1.8.0_301 JVM: 25.301-b09(Oracle Corporation) Arch: amd64
New Dep: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.3-34.1.42_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Tutorial'.
> Invalid patcher dependency: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.3-34.1.42:userdev

[...]

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.

[...]

BUILD FAILED in 6s`

Comment: Clear your gradle caches (navigate to %UserProfile%\.gradle\cache). Delete this folder and then run gradlew eclipse

Comment: It works, thank You!

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the 'tick' icon, so it may help others.